# How to JOIN data from two different tables?

Tags: sql, join

Table 1: Building

```
    ProjectNO (FK)
    BuildingNO
    Floors
    location
```

Table 2: Project

```
    ProjectNO (PK)
    ProjectName
    CityName
```

I need to join `"project"` and `"Building"` because I need the common `Buildings` in `Project` and `Building` by the key `ProjectNO`.

thank you

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: So...if you know you need to join the 2 tables, why don't you do it???

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you know you want to do a join, so you need to research how joins work and try doing it yourself. Then come back for help after you actually try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `inner join` keyword to get matching records from both tables.

If you have 2 tables with the same `ProjectNO` to be joined,

```
select * from Project p
     inner join
     Building b
     on p.ProjectNO = b.ProjectNO;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seems want :

```
select b.*
from Building b
where exists (select 1 from Project p where p.ProjectNO = b.ProjectNO);
```

If you want ProjectName, CityName then you can do `JOIN` :

```
select p.*, b.*
from Project p inner join
     Building b
     on p.ProjectNO = b.ProjectNO;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do inner join to get matching record from both tables like follows...

```
SELECT * FROM Building INNER JOIN Project ON Project.ProjectNO=Building.ProjectNO;
```

it will return only those records whose ProjectNO exists in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

just use `inner join` because The INNER JOIN keyword selects records that have matching values in both tables.

```
  select p.*, b.ProjectName
    from Project p inner join
         Building b
         on p.ProjectNO = b.ProjectNO;
```